UPDATE STATISTICS best practice
In following scenario what do you think is best option for update statistics
Database around 1 TB
One table has 4 billion records
Right now we run daily UPDATE STATISTICS (without specifying anything SAMPLE PERCENT)
Should we WITH SAMPLE ?? PERCENT
